# Convert Unix Date "Wed Sep 15 14:21:36 2010" to unix timestamp in perl or MySQL to store in mySQL

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to convert a regular Unix date in human readable format back into unix timestamp without making arrays for Months and Days of the week. 
Obviously the "%" needs to be escaped in perl
I tried "%%" and "\%" and RTM, which is how I ended up with \%%

```
$myDate="Wed Sep 15 14:21:36 2010";
$datePattern="\%%a \%%b \%%e \%%H:\%%i:\%%s \%%Y";
```

MySQL has a function

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP (STR_TO_DATE (\'$myDate\' \, \'$datePattern\'))";
```

My final statement looks like this:
The command works directly from mySQL but not when I call it from perl.

```
replace mytable values ('some value', UNIX_TIMESTAMP (STR_TO_DATE (\'$myDate\' \, \'$datePattern\')))";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Date::Manip](https://metacpan.org/module/Date%3a%3aManip%3a%3aDM5)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    $Date::Manip::Backend = 'DM5';
}
use Date::Manip;
my $myDate = "Wed Sep 15 14:21:36 2010";
print Date::Manip::UnixDate( $myDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' );
```

or look through the [DateTime modules](http://datetime.perl.org/wiki/datetime/page/Modules)

Here is my try at DateTime. One with the mysql DateTime module and one without.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime::Format::MySQL;

my $myDate = "Wed Sep 15 14:21:36 2010";
my $Strp   = new DateTime::Format::Strptime( pattern => '%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y', );
my $dt     = $Strp->parse_datetime($myDate);

print $dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') . "\n";

print DateTime::Format::MySQL->format_datetime($dt) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Another choice might be to use Time::Piece

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
my $mydate = "Wed Sep 15 14:21:36 2010";
my $mytime = Time::Piece->strptime($mydate, "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y");
print $mytime->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [Date::Parse](https://metacpan.org/module/Date::Parse):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Date::Parse;

my $date = "Wed Sep 15 14:21:36 2010";
my $time = str2time($date);
```

From there, you can issue a query that updates the database records to use `$time`.

Comment: `use Date::Parse;`
seems like the most elegant solution to me.